# Creating a simple Linkedlist

Tags: linked-list

How do I correct this error?

> Error:  Node cannot be resolved to a type;

My code goes like this:

```
public class Linkedlist
{
    private Node head;
    private int listCount;
}
```

Comment: Missing `import Node`?

Comment: This question is missing a language tag. It is therefore impossible to know what language this is supposed to be. Please add a [tag:c++], [tag:java], or whatever tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Linkedlist {

private Node head;

private int listCount;

}

public class Node{
}
```

You need to make sure `Node` is accesible

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Object cannot be resolved to a type" indicates that the compiler cannot find the declaration of the given object that needs to be instantiated. In other words, the compiler can't figure out what blueprint needs to be read in order to create a Node.

To fix this, you have two simple options.

1. Declare Node as a nested class within LinkedList.

   ```
   public class LinkedList{
       private Node head;
       private int listCount;
       } 
   private class Node {
     //Include instance variables and constructor
    }
    }
   ```
2. Declare Node as a public class within another java file in the same directory.

   ```
   public class Node{
   ```

   }